# Is it possible to use htaccess to rewrite URLs without file extensions with MultiViews on

Tags: .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I'm using the following .htaccess file in order to internally rewrite URLs without the file extension, i.e. /mypage opens the content of /mypage.php or /mypage.html

```
Options -MultiViews

# start rewrite engine
RewriteEngine on

# internally rewrite "page" to "page.html"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.html [NC,L]

# internally rewrite "page" to "page.php"
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php [NC,L]
```

It works exactly is it should on my local WAMP server.

However on my shared hosting service it gives an Internal server Error (500).
My hosting provider told me that the error log says that "Option MultiViews not allowed here" and confirmed me that MultiViews is enabled by default.
If I comment the first line there is no Error 500 but the rewriting doesn't work anymore (because MultiViews is enabled). They said to me that they can not change it for my host.

So is it possible for me to get this .htaccess rewriting URL working with MultiViews on ?